# How can I insert padding between the different bins of my dodged histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**I would like padding between each of the bins in my dodged histogram so that the bars in each bin are clearly grouped together.** How can I do this with `ggplot`?

This is my working example:

```
library(ggplot)
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>%
    filter(clarity %in% c("VS2", "VS1", "VVS2", "VVS1")) %>%
    ggplot +
    geom_histogram(
        aes(x = price, fill = clarity),
        breaks = seq(10000, 20000, 2500),
        color = "black",
        position = "dodge"
    )
```

Comment: Why breaks starting at 10000 when `min(price) == 327`?

Answer (score 2):

Histograms do not have space between bars, only bar plots do. So the solution is to use `geom_bar` instead. But first the data must be binned manually with `cut`. Then the space between bars within the groups is increased by setting `position_dodge(width = 0.8)`.

```
diamonds %>%
  filter(clarity %in% c("VS2", "VS1", "VVS2", "VVS1")) %>%
  mutate(price = cut(price, breaks = seq(250, 20000, 2500), labels = seq(250, 20000, 2500)[-1])) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(
    aes(x = price, fill = clarity),
    width = 0.5,
    color = "black",
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Including `!between(price, 5000, 15000)` in the `filter()` shows no spaces displaying for bins that have no prices. Is there a way to keep those spaces even when their bins have no observations?